# New files are not adding to Azure from BitBucket

Tags: azure, bitbucket, azure-web-app-service

my application has deployed on Bitbucket, where our team members commit the code.  in Azure I set to sync website from Bitbucket 'xyz' branch . When I make changes in 'xyz' branch it's working fine and are mapping on my azure's website.But when I create new file(s) and commit the code in bitbucket and push my changes then Azure don't show these files on website. I think there is an option in Azure or Bitbucket for publishing new files but after searching for hours I can't find the solution, please help.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't see any deployment happening, or that you see a deployment but then it doesn't do what you expect? If the latter, please start with [these steps](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-vs-runtime-issues)

Comment: Also, please clarify the kind of app you're deploying, e.g. .NET, Node, etc...

Comment: @DavidEbbo thanks for your comments, deployment is happening and azure syncing  complete with no error. but I couldn't see new file file which i have uploaded to bitbucket server. I have found the solution. the error was coming from .csproj file , it was not properly uploading to server at each commit .and you know all new file information are adding in .csproj file's xml tags.

Comment: Yep, that would do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I was copying files from other project and without debug I was uploading it to bitbucket server, this caused no effect on .scproj and .dll files so only the files were uploading which I have created . From azure deployment, i think, it see into .csproj file, if file exist it pick up and sync new changes but my new files were not adding to .csproj file's xml tag. 
In short the main issue was .csproj and .dll files were not uploading .